# How do I continue the dictionary in C# that reads a simple text file with sort by towns - problem from an authors book?

Tags: c#, dictionary, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a simple text file that reads names, cities and cell phone numbers. The code below shows dictionary, array and is C# programming. The SortedDictionary is sorted by the Key which here it is 'Cities' got it? The code below gets me an index out of bounds error and I need help fixing it.
My error is here:

```
    string name = entry[0].Trim();  
    string town = entry[1].Trim(); //index out of bounds error    
    string phone = entry[2].Trim();
```

My text file unsorted:

```
Names
    Cities
        Cell Phone Numbers
Kennedy
    Nairobi
        1-234-567-8911
Silas
    Lusaka
        2-345-678-9112
Joseph
    Jerusalem
        3-456-789-1112
Diana
    Kisumu
        4-567-891-2345
Winston
    Migori
        5-678-912-3456
```

The code looks like this:

```
 using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sort_Dictionary_Script
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Read the file and build the phone book
            SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, string>>
            phonesByTown = new SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, string>>();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("PhoneBook.txt");
            using (reader)
            {
                int x = 1;
                while (x <= 4)
                {
                    x++;
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (line == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }                  
                    string[] entry = line.Split(new char[] { '|' });
                    string name = entry[0].Trim();
                    string town = entry[1].Trim();
                    string phone = entry[2].Trim();
                    SortedDictionary<string, string> phoneBook;
                    // When a program often has to try keys that turn out not to
                    // be in the dictionary, TryGetValue can be a more efficient
                    // way to retrieve values.
                    if (!phonesByTown.TryGetValue(town, out phoneBook))
                    {
                        //This town is new. Create a phone book for it.
                        phoneBook = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
                        phonesByTown.Add(town, phoneBook);
                    }
                    phoneBook.Add(name, phone);
                   
                }
            }
            //Print the phone book by towns
            foreach (string town in phonesByTown.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Town " + town + ":");
                SortedDictionary<string, string> phoneBook = phonesByTown[town];
                foreach (var entry in phoneBook)
                {
                    string name = entry.Key;
                    string phone = entry.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0} - {1}", name, phone);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you show me how to fix the index out of bounds error?
I have spent some time reading around and still don't get it. What do I need to do to get better at this?
I'm reading a code from a book I am reading that has this and the code doesn't work. And I am self-taught.

Comment: Your text file doesn't contain `|` - why are you splitting your lines by this character?

Comment: Anyway, if you split `"a|b"` by `'|'` then you will get an array with two strings: `"a"` and `"b"`. If you split `"hello"` by `'|'` then you will get an array with one string: `"hello"`. Your string doesn't contain any `|` characters, so `entry` will always be an array of length 1. As such, you can't access the second (`entry[1]`) or third (`entry[2]`) elements because they don't exist.

Comment: Does your text file really look exactly like that? Name with no spaces, city on next line indented by 4 spaces, cell on next line indented by 8 spaces? Can you edit your text file or do you have to work with it as is?

Comment: Yes, I have the text and it didn't include pipe characters anywhere so I added them. I appreciate for looking into my code. Now it works! Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that some line in your text file does not fulfill your formatting requirements. I.e. some line in the file does not contain two `|` characters. You can skip such lines by inserting a check

```
if(entry.Length < 3){
    // continue, or use some other error handling
}
```

I would recommend reading Eric Lipperts [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Errors like these are quite common, but they should also be very easy to find with a debugger. If you run the program in the visual studio debugger the it should stop at the exception, allowing you to inspect the exception, and any related variables causing the exception. There is also the exception settings dialog that can be used to break when exceptions are thrown, even if they are handled.

Comment: My output was not getting the pipe characters because I just added them. That goes to show that I was overthinking the problem when I should have warily viewed the step by step of the array. Now I get this. Solution worked Thank you!